# Nodejs send mails

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I've sent some mails using express mailer. My problem is, when I need to send mails it's asking for my credentials and using that email to send. However, I want to send emails from a no-reply email but this would mean sending emails from an account thats not set up.

I know in other application servers you can pretty much send emails from any email address, even one which is not your own. I'm wondering how I can do this with nodejs or expressjs.

Edit:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'yang@example.com',
        pass: '****'
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'noreply@send.com',
    to: 'yang@receive.com',
    subject: 'Hello ✔',
    text: 'Hello world ✔',
    html: '<b>Hello world ✔</b>'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

I've tried this but it's still sending from yang@example.com which is the server I logged in with

Comment: I would suggest using nodemailer if you really want to send your own email.  However, think seriously about using a service like Mandrill as sending your own email has a lot of pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Google SMTP servers automatically set your sending address to the one you logged in with.

If you want to send e-mail with an address which isn't your own, you should use a different SMTP server or set up your own one ([Haraka](https://github.com/andris9/smtp-server), [smtp-server](https://github.com/andris9/smtp-server), etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the "reply-to" or "from" to whatever you need to.  It's independent of which email account you use to send the email.  Like an address on a postage mail envelope.

Nodemailer is a bit more robust in my personal experience: https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodemailer

And for higher volume setting up a service like Amazon SES as your transport.